# Restore Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have an application that displays a table of data with a publish button. You can select the rows and then click to publish them. The selected data is packaged up in the necessary json format and sent via ajax to do a quick check that none of the data has any dependencies. If there are dependencies then it returns an error message and a list of those dependencies. You must then select the dependencies plus the parent and try to publish again. The problem is after manipulating the data once to the correct json format to send for the first call, the data then seems to be unusable and missing in the model altogether...I can make the call once but not again. Any help is much appreciated! Here is my controller:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
actions: {

    publishSubmit: function(){

        var checkedItems = this.get('model').filterBy('isChecked', true);

        if(checkedItems.length > 0){

            this.send('dependencyCheck', checkedItems);
        }
        else{
            this.announce.error('No items selected for publish.');
        }
    },

    dependencyCheck: function(items){
        var _this = this, data = [];

        items.forEach(function(item){
            delete item._data.isChecked;
            delete item._data.sortByDate;
            item._data.publisherId = item._data.id;
            delete item._data.id;
            item._data.updatedDate = null;
            data.push(item._data);
        });

        //data formating(required)
        data = _this.capitalizeAll(data);
        data = JSON.stringify(data);

        console.log(data);

        Ember.$.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("Token", sessionStorage.getItem('authToken'));
            },
            url: config.host + '/AssessmentPublishService/DependentPublishableItems',
            data: data
        }).then(function(dependencies){

            var processDependencies = _this.processResponseData(dependencies);

            if(dependencies.Status === "Success"){

                console.log("ProccessD");
                console.log(processDependencies);

                return JSON.stringify(processDependencies);
            }
            else{
                return this.announce.error('Failed to process.');
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mutate the model in the first call to `dependencyCheck`. By using `delete` you put the model into a bad state. You should not use `_data` (it's private, as hinted by the underscore)

```
    items.forEach(function(item){
        delete item._data.isChecked;
        delete item._data.sortByDate;
        item._data.publisherId = item._data.id;
        delete item._data.id;
        item._data.updatedDate = null;
        data.push(item._data);
    });
```

You can take whatever values you need without changing the model:

```
    items.forEach(function(item){
        data.push({
          publisherId: item.get('id'),
          updatedDate: null
          // etc
        });
    });
```

Better yet, call [serialize](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_serialize) on the model and [configure the serializer](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/customizing-serializers/) to include the properties you want.

```
    var data = items.map(model => model.serialize());
    data = this.capitalizeAll(data);
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: You absolutely nailed it. I was misunderstanding what I was doing by manipulating the private data. once modified I was altering the data permanently. so i did as you suggested and pushed it piecemeal into a new structure. i don't quite understand the map/serializing approach. it may be above my pay grade. thanks a lot for your help!